# linux sed remove block of code with linebreak

Tags: linux, sed

Trying to remove this entire block of code from a script:

https://pastebin.com/gBnFBQSR

I am able to do so up until the linebreak and ending }

```
sed '/var gfjfgjk/,/appendChild(s);\n}/d'
```

how can I have it include the linebreak and } at the end

Comment: [Same issue posted at RU SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076647/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: The same issue remains, it doesn't remove the very last closing } example, after I run it, here is the first line of the js: `}/**` instead of `/**`

Comment: Oh wow nevermind, I see it now, thank you

Comment: Seems on-topic to me.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368711/are-sed-awk-and-text-processing-questions-valid-on-stack-overflow-anymore

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, textable, textual sample input and expected output so we can help you. No links, no images, just text that demonstrates your problem and that we could test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew link:

```
for i in $(grep -rl gfjfgjk) ; do if grep -m1 gfjfgjk $i >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo $i ; sed -i -e '1,6d;7s/^}//' $i ; fi; done
```

The only different really is, I wanted to make sure gfjfgjk matched the first line of the file in case it was injected somewhere else in the script and then sed removed the first 7 lines of legit code.

Comment: Don't do that, whatever it is you're trying to do there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, would you please try the following:

```
sed '
:l      # define a label "l"
N       # read next line and append to the pattern space
$!b l   # goto "l" unless eof
s/var gfjfgjk.*appendChild(s);\n}//
        # remove the specified block including newlines
' file
```

It first slurps all lines into the pattern space so we can process
  multiple lines (including the newline characters) at once.

The possible problem is if the file contains the pattern `appendChild(s);\n}`
in multiple lines, `sed` will fall in the `longest match` due to the
`greedy` nature of regex.

As an alternative, if `perl` is your option, you can also say:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/var gfjfgjk.*?appendChild\(s\);\n}//s' file
```

- The `-0777` option tells `perl` to read the all lines at once.
- The regex `.*?` enables the `shortest` match.
- The `s` option at the end makes the dot `.` match newlines. Otherwise
  the dot in `perl` regex does not match newlines.